# Check if the array is descending up to the local minimum and then ascending after it in C

Tags: arrays, c

**My task is: The user should input numbers until -1 is pressed. The array consisting of those elements should be formed. I need to check is the array is descending up to the local minimum and ascending after it. If this condition is satisfied 'Yes' should be printed, 'No' in the opposite case.
I don't know what is wrong with my code, so I hope you could help. I am beginner.

```
int main() {
    int a[100],n=0,b,i,j=0,c=0,h;
    for (i=0;i<100;i++){
        if (b==-1)
            break;
        else {scanf("%d", &b);
            a[i]=b;
            n++;
        }
    }
    if (n<3)
        printf("Not enough elements");

    else{
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                a[j]=a[i];
        }
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            if (a[i]>a[i+1] && i!=n-1)
                continue;
            else if (a[i]<a[i+1]){
                c=1;
                h=i;
                break;
            }
        }    


        if (c==1 && h==i){
            for(j=i;j<n;i++){
                if(a[j]<a[j+1])
                    continue;
                else if(a[j]>a[j+1] || a[j+1]==a[j]){
                    break;
                    c=0;
                }

            }
            if(j==n-1 && c==1)
                printf("Yes");
            else if (c==0)
                printf("No");   
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I am not convinced that you need an array. Your code looks way too complex. You need a "previous value" and a value indicating whether you are still descending. Also: in the first iteration `b` is not initialised.

Comment: State in the question why you think something is wrong with your code. What input (copy and paste exact text) gives a bad result? What bad result does it give? What result do you want instead? Generally, edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: There is an issue with your first double for loop, you set all the element of a to the last value of the array

Comment: I suspect that `if(a[j]>a[j+1] || a[j+1]==a[j]){ break; c=0; }` should be `if(a[j]>=a[j+1]){ c=0; break; }` The line `c=0;` is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[100],n=0,b,i,j=0,c=0,h;
    do
    {
        printf("Give me a number :");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        a[j]=b;
        j++;
    }while(b!=-1);
    i=0;
    j--;
    if (j<3)
    {
        printf("Not enough elements");
    }
    else
    {
        i=0;
        while(i<j-1 && a[i]>a[i+1])
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(i==j-1)
        {
            printf("No");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            c=i;
            while(a[c+1]>a[c]&&c<j-1)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(c==j-1)
    {
        printf("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No");
    }
}
```